# Why Global this not accesible inside object?

Tags: javascript

Why Global this not accessible inside object?

```js
name = 'Name1';

const person = {
  name: 'Name2',
  greet: () => {
    console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name);
  }
}

person.greet();
```

`this.name` shows `undefined`, should be `Name1`.

Comment: Because, arrow function does not have it's own `this`....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Try any variable name other than `name`, it conflicts with `window.name`.

Comment: Mamun got correct answer not the supposed to be duplicate question answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of issues with using `this` and `()=>{}` notation.

```
name = 'Name1';

const person = {
  name: 'Name2',
  greet: function () {
    console.log('Hi, I am ' + this.name);
  }
}

person.greet();
```